# hi ! rinkeby faucet is not working for me . can you send me some eth to 0x302e745701790A85BEEEB6340c2F1c7ddbeef959

Tags: ether, rinkeby, faucets

rinkeby faucet is not working .some rinkeby eth required please

Comment: For anyone looking to run a testnet on Ethereum, Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet still supported after the recent Ethereum Merge. All others (Rinkeby, Ropsten, Kovan, etc) have been deprecated and isn’t working.

If you need any free Goerli testETH, here's a reliable faucet by Alchemy - https://goerlifaucet.com. If you need them, they've got good dev docs (https://docs.alchemy.com).

Answer (score 0):

Here we are this works good , enjoy ;)
https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby